# Move to UITAB BAR Controller from a simple view controller

Tags: ios, view, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

Friends i have a simple view controller .. in which there are 4 buttons . on any button press i want to go to tab bar controller . but on first button press , first tab of tab bar controller should open ... and on 2nd button press 2nd tab of tab bar controller should b open , same for 3rd and 4th button ... Please help me ... i m new in iphone development ... i cant found any way to do it ... :(

[image]

```
self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init]; 
UIViewController *viewController1 = [[firstViewController alloc] init]; 
UIViewController *viewController2 = [[secondViewController alloc] init];   

self.tabBarController.viewControllers=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:viewController1,viewController2, nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this way when you first button was clicked pass this

```
self.tabBar.selectedIndex = 0;
```

change the 0 with your button number like for second button you can pass

```
self.tabBar.selectedIndex = 1;
```

and so on....

Comment: i try this on IBAction ... but it is not working ... even app is not moving to tab bar controller

Comment: @BuAli : are you using navigationController as rootview? please paste your code for creating a tabbar so that i can check and help you.

Comment: [4:33:38 AM] Iphone Developer:    self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    
    UIViewController *viewController1 = [[firstViewController alloc] init];
    UIViewController *viewController2 = [[secondViewController alloc] init];
    
    self.tabBarController.viewControllers=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:viewController1,viewController2, nil];

Comment: @BuAli : are you using storyboard?